# Add Label around circle value

Tags: wpf, geometry

So i have `Circular Progress-Bar` and i want to position `Label` around circle `Value`.

This is what i have try:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="25" Percentage="100" Radius="100"/>
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="0" SegmentColor="Red" StrokeThickness="25" Radius="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="vlb" Content="{Binding ElementName=circle, Path=Percentage}" Margin="-50,-50,-50,-50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="3600.12"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
    </Label.RenderTransform>                                                  
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

Now inside my `Timer` tick i raised my Circelr percentage by 1 every second:

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double d = circle.Percentage += 1;
    var radius = 100;
    var sangle = (d * 360) / 100;
    double angleRad = (Math.PI / 180.0) * (sangle - 90);
    double x = radius * Math.Cos(angleRad);
    double y = radius * Math.Sin(angleRad);
    vlb.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform { Angle = sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
}
```

And the result is that my `Label` is now straight:

[image]

**Update**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" SegmentColor="#FF878889" StrokeThickness="25" Percentage="100" Radius="100"/>
            <DesignInControl:CircularProgressBar x:Name="circle" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Percentage="0" SegmentColor="SeaGreen" StrokeThickness="25" Radius="100"/>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
    <Label x:Name="vlb_outer" Margin="-50,-50,-50,-50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="50"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
        <Label Content="{Binding ElementName=circle, Path=Percentage}" FontSize="20" x:Name="vlb_inner">
            <Label.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <RotateTransform Angle="-50"/>
                </TransformGroup>
            </Label.RenderTransform>
        </Label>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

**Result**

[image]

```
Update
```

Start position:

[image]

After raise `Value` by `1`:

[image]

The `Label` is little on the left size.

Comment: So... what's your question then? In which way do you want your result to differ?

Comment: How to change this Label rotation ?

Comment: What does your code look like in the last edit and what are the values on each variable?

Comment: The Question is somewhat unclear. Can you describe your visual desired result? Using labels, transformations or other technical components to construct the visual only makes sense after clearly defining the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I never used transforms in wpf before, but since I have a game dev background, this was quite easy to handle for me:

I created a child-`Label` which has the binding and its own `TransformGroup`, like this:

```
<Label x:Name="vlb_outer" Margin="-50,-50,-50,-50" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" Grid.RowSpan="2">
    <Label.RenderTransform>
        <TransformGroup>
            <ScaleTransform/>
            <SkewTransform/>
            <RotateTransform Angle="50"/>
            <TranslateTransform/>
        </TransformGroup>
    </Label.RenderTransform>
    <Label Content="{Binding Value}" x:Name="vlb_inner">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <RotateTransform Angle="-50"/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
</Label>
```

Now what I did in code was simple, I just assigned the rotationvalue to the `vlb_outer` element and the negative rotationvalue to the `vlb_inner` element. This way it will be rotated back by the same angle in the opposite direction around its own center.

```
vlb_outer.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = value };
vlb_inner.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = -value };
```

I simplified everything for me since I do not have your code, but it seemed to work. I tried it with a slider from 0 to 360 and made a binding of the value to the `Content` and the rotation.

Hope it helps.

**Edit**

Okay, so because you did not like the location (obviously), I played around with my calculation and trust me, I hate hardcoded values, but in this case, they helped me a lot.

My current code looks like this:

```
private void Rotate(double value)
{
    double sangle = value * 360 + 42;
    vlb_outer.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
    vlb_inner.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = -sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
    Value = (int)(value*360);
}
```

It gets the value (from 0 to 1) and multiplies it by 360 (for the rotation) and a magic number that fixes your starting location. I don't think that 42 is perfect, but something around that worked for me.

**Edit**

This code should work for you

```
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double sangle = circle.Percentage * 3.6 + 42;
    vlb_outer.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
    vlb_inner.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform() { Angle = -sangle, CenterX = 0, CenterY = 0 };
}
```

Comment: Please my update, i added your code and the result, the Label now is OK but still in wrong direction

Comment: This wierd, it did the desired rotation in my version.

Comment: Maybe you know another approach to add this Label over my Circle ?

Comment: I just updated my code post, I hope this works for you. Since it is a rotation and not a position, hardcoded values do not seem to be extremely bad.

Comment: Inside Rotate function, what this Value variable ? from where this came  ?

Comment: Oh, this is the value of the slider coming from an event. In your case it may be the percentage of the circle, divided by 100.0

Comment: I did not understand how this works, i have this Timer tick. what should i put inside ?

Comment: In your case this line should be `double sangle = circle.percentage*3.6+42;`

Comment: but i need your function instead all my timer tick ? can you post here all the timer tick ?

Comment: I only call this method from the event and give it the value of the slider. I do not use timer_tick, because there is no timer in my code. Just replace your code within timer_tick with my code and change `value` to `circle.percentage * 0.01`. Just look at my last edit.

Comment: Please see last update, this works fine now, just the label is little on the left size

Answer (score 0):

I think you just screwed up your positioning and margin. I don't have your circle controls, so I just use a static yellow circle to move the label around with a slider for demonstration:

```
<Grid>
    <Slider x:Name="angleProvider" Minimum="0" Maximum="360" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Center" MinWidth="100" Margin="10"/>
    <Ellipse
        Width="50" Height="50"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Fill="Yellow"/>
    <Label
        Content="{Binding ElementName=angleProvider,Path=Value}" ContentStringFormat="{}{0:##0'°'}"
        RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5"
        Width="80" Height="80"
        Padding="0"
        VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Top" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">
        <Label.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=angleProvider,Path=Value}"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
        </Label.RenderTransform>
    </Label>
</Grid>
```

So basically, place the center of your label at the same position as the center of the circles, position the label content centered at the top, set width and height bigger than the circles so the text appears outside, rotate the label around its center.

Note I didn't check which of the transforms other than `RotateTransform` you actually need. I think all the others can be deleted from the `TransformGroup`.